# How to generate a PowerPoint slideshow using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, uwp, openxml, presentationml

I am writing a UWP application that will be used to generate a powerpoint presentation. This presentation will contain slides from several other powerpoint presentations as well as textual content that is defined by my application. I have been attempting to use the OpenXML classes provided by microsoft to generate the powerpoints but I am having seriously frustrating issues with it.

I want to have multiple named sections within my presentation, but I can't seem to figure out how to generate them in C# in a way that allows powerpoint to see them. Does anyone know how to add sections to a slideshow using OpenXML?

I would also like to copy slides from other presentations, and I am concerned that this might not be a simple task either.

I am not required to use OpenXML (it's just what I have landed on thus far), so if there is a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to do I would love to hear about it! Please note however that I can't afford to spend $500+ on a solution to this, and I can't have watermarks on all of the slides either. I can afford a one-time fee possibly, but anything else is more than I can spend. Obviously a free solution would be optimal.

Comment: This may be more intuitive for PowerPoint and working with the SDK. Feels a little bit like good ol' VBA of the old days. https://github.com/ShapeCrawler/ShapeCrawler

Answer (score 0):

I had not intended to answer my own question, but I was able to find a workable solution (though it took awhile).

As it turns out, Syncfusion has a community license for their software which fulfills my needs. For anyone that might be interested there are restrictions regarding how you will be using their software and how much your business makes (if that applies). If you fit their requirements then you just have to provide a Linked-in account and you're all set!

Syncfusion's PowerPoint interface is so much easier to use than the default OpenXML classes provided by Microsoft. I highly recommend looking into it if you need to do a lot of office data generation.